# How to manage the X element from a list of elements with the same class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have these elements :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="myTarget">a</div>
    <div class="notMyTarget">b</div>
    <div class="myTarget">c</div>
    <div class="notMyTarget">d</div>
    <div class="myTarget">e</div>
    <div class="myTarget">f</div>
    <div class="notMyTarget">g</div>
    <div class="myTarget">h</div>
    <div class="notMyTarget">i</div>
    <div class="notMyTarget">j</div>
    <div class="myTarget">k</div>
    <div class="myTarget">l</div>
    <div class="notMyTarget">m</div>
    <div class="myTarget">n</div>
    <div class="myTarget">o</div>
</div>
```

and I'd like to remove (for example) the 4° elements of the `myTarget`'s collections div that are children of `container`. So in this case, I'd like to remove the one with `f`.

What's the best and easy way to do it on jQuery? .index() can help?

Comment: Would it need to be dynamic or would it be fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the (zero-indexed) [`:eq()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector):

```
$('.container .myTarget:eq(3)').remove();
```

Counting up from 0, 3 represents the fourth `.myTarget` element.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.container div').eq(5).remove()
```

Where 5 is the index.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(".container").find(".myTarget:eq(3)").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) selector :

```
$('.container .myTarget:eq(3)').remove();
```